# How arrow-> operator overloading works internally in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I understand the normal operator overloading. Compiler can translate them to method call directly. I am not very clear about the -> operator. I was writing my first custom iterator and I felt like the need of -> operator. I took a look at the stl source code and implemented my own like it:

```
MyClass* MyClassIterator::operator->() const
{
    //m_iterator is a map<int, MyClass>::iterator in my code.
    return &(m_iterator->second);
}
```

Then I can use an instance of MyClassIterator like:

```
myClassIterator->APublicMethodInMyClass().
```

Looks like the compiler does two steps here.
1. Call the ->() method the get a temporary MyClass* variable.
2. Call the APublicMethodInMyClass on the temp variable use its -> operator.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
myClassIterator->APublicMethodInMyClass()
```

is nothing but the following:

```
myClassIterator.operator->()->APublicMethodInMyClass()
```

The first call to the overloaded `operator->` gets you a pointer of some type which has an accessible (from your call-site) member function called `APublicMethodInMyClass()`. The usual function look-up rules are followed to resolve `APublicMethodInMyClass()`, of course, depending on whether it is a virtual or not.

There is not necessarily a temporary variable; the compiler may or may not copy *the pointer* returned by `&(m_iterator->second)`. In all probability, this will be optimized away. No temporary objects of type `MyClass` will be created though.

The usual caveats also do apply to `m_iterator` -- make sure that your calls do not access an invalidated iterator (i.e. if you are using `vector` for example).

Comment: Also see http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+drill-down%20operator . The arrow operator is subtly unique in C++.

Comment: @Potatoswatter which link should we read? A link to a google search isn't really that helpful.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c

Comment: @Seth well I wrote two of the top three, so take your pick ;v) . But the top one is a good choice.

Comment: @Potatoswatter ah thank you, I had never heard of the drill-down behaviour. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 102):

The `operator->` has special semantics in the language in that, when overloaded, it reapplies itself to the result. While the rest of the operators are applied only once, `operator->` will be applied by the compiler as many times as needed to get to a raw pointer and once more to access the memory referred by that pointer.

```
struct A { void foo(); };
struct B { A* operator->(); };
struct C { B operator->(); };
struct D { C operator->(); };
int main() {
   D d;
   d->foo();
}
```

In the previous example, in the expression `d->foo()` the compiler will take the object `d` and apply `operator->` to it, which yields an object of type `C`, it will then reapply the operator to get an instance of `B`, reapply and get to `A*`, after which it will dereference the object and get to the pointed data.

```
d->foo();
// expands to:
// (*d.operator->().operator->().operator->()).foo();
//   D            C            B           A*
```

Comment: Can you point me to a reference on this? Can't seem to find any. Nobody else even mentions it.

Comment: @MilindR: 13.5.6/1[...] *An expression x->m is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object x of type T if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism* If `x->operator->()` yields a pointer, it gets dereferenced, if it yields an object of a type that overloads `operator->()` that operator gets called.

Comment: @MilindR: The accepted answer does say this, although it is not so explicit on the meaning: `myClassIterator.operator->()->APublicMethodInMyClass()` (second piece of code)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, you can infer some recursion from the second line of accepted answer's code, but it is better explained in your answer (In fact, the recursion was not visible to me until I read yours). Thank you !

Comment: All this time I thought I had to manually write the recursion to fetch the pointer. +1 for the odd tidbit.