# How does Herb Sutters monitor class work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand the monitor class that Herb Sutter presented on C++ and Beyond 2012:

```
template<typename T>
class monitor {
private:
    mutable T t;
    mutable std::mutex m;

public:
    monitor(T t_ = T{}) : t{ t_ } {} 
    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(t))
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _{ m }; return f(t);
    }
};
```

I have managed to create a class that does the same thing in a more old fashioned and simpler (for me at least) way:

```
template<typename T>
class MyMonitor {
public:
    MyMonitor() { t = T(); }

    template<typename F>
    auto callFunc(F f) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        return f(t);
    }

private:
    T          t;
    std::mutex m;
};
```

In which ways are Herb Sutters code better than mine?

Comment: There is fundamental difference, your class doesn't handle properly reference returnd by functor `F`. You just discard it.

Comment: Don't understand. Are you saying that if a functor f returns a reference my monitor will not work?

Comment: Using a constructor initialiser list, where possible, is considered preferable over assignment in the constructor body, since it involves constructing less objects.   Point to Herb. Being able to use a object specified as `const` is preferable to being unable to use it. Point to Herb. Being explicit about the return value of `operator()` being the type returned by `f()` means less potential confusion for the programmer about the return type. Point to Herb.  Being able to properly handle functors that return a reference.  Point to Herb. Using variable named `_` hurts readability.  Point to you.

Comment: Note that `auto` functions without a trailing return type were added in C++14 (so they aren't that old-fashioned), and follow the normal rule that `auto` is never a reference.

Comment: @Andy Yes, exactly. Your `operator()` will return by value if the functor returns by reference. You can use `decltype(auto)` as return value to get the same behaviour as Herbs code without trailing return type.

Comment: Theres a much nicer way to write a monitor class than Herbs idea (at least its nicer to use) using a wrapper monitor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647217/making-a-c-class-a-monitor-in-the-concurrent-sense/48408987#48408987

Comment: @Peter: regarding your first point: yes I see now that where Herb calls a copy ctor I call a ctor + an assignment operator. Thanks. Silly mistake. I would replace this by: MyMonitor() : t(T()) { ; } where I use one temporary object less than Herb. Herb on the other hand supports adoption which is probably useful.

Comment: @MikeVine: I prefer this one which allows to "protect" any block of code. whereas the `operator->` only allow to protect a method call (so cannot protect 3 `push_back` in a row).

Comment: @Jarod42 Did you read the answer? It lets you do it either way - you can protect a block very easily. See the part about `lockedHandle`.

Comment: In fact, if you wanted to you could combine both answers and add the lambda syntax to my wrapper monitor class and then you can pick and choose your ways of accessing in a thread safe manner.

Comment: That answer allows universal way. Your `ManuallyLock` seems so old fashioned (extra (unnatural) scope). Lambda scopes are "automatic".

Comment: @Peter: If I rewrite to use mutable I can do this: std::vector<int> ivec; const MyMonitor<std::vector<int>> ivecm(ivec); ivecm.callFunc([](std::vector<int> &ivec) { ivec.push_back(1); }); Does this make sense? I can declare something as const and then still change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In which ways are Herb Sutters code better than mine?

- Your `T` should be default constructible, and assignable.
- In Herb Sutters code, `T` should be copy constructible.
- Herb Sutters code allows to initialize the member.
- Your `operator ()` doesn't handle reference.

Comment: also OPs `operator()` is not const-correct, but I guess thats the minor issue

Comment: @idclev463035818: `mutable` and `const` versus not `const`...

Comment: yes, what I meant is that it should be `const` but isnt, which prevents to use a `const monitor` when it should be possible

Comment: *"it should be const"*. Not sure, whereas `mutex` indeed doesn't change const semantic of the object, modifying `T` is more controversal IMO.

Comment: Are you sure about the second point? I wrote a Dummy class that prints out inside constructor etc. Herbs code:
Dummy ctor,
Dummy copy ctor,
Dummy dtor.

Comment: @Andy: Try to use `struct S { S(int) {} };` And then `monitor<S> m(42);`

Comment: ah ok, understand your point. Depends on what semantics `monitor` should offer, both choices are "correct"

Comment: Do not understand your point about semantics. If I rewrite to use mutable I can do this: std::vector<int> ivec; const MyMonitor<std::vector<int>> ivecm(ivec); ivecm.callFunc([](std::vector<int> &ivec) { ivec.push_back(1); }); Does this make sense? I can declare something as const and then still change it?

Comment: **Reading** a synchronized resource which require to lock `mutex` should not be`const`, because of the `mutex`, but it might be seen as `const` semantically as you don't modify the resource itself. so `mutable` `mutex` is ok, but as I said `mutable` resource is controversial. Ideally, we want 2 overloads, one const and one not.