# Thread-safe locking of instance with multiple member functions

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a struct instance that gets used by multiple threads. Each thread contains an unknown amount of function calls that alter the struct member variable.

I have a dedicated function that tries to "reserve" the struct instance for the current thread and I would like to ensure no other thread can reserve the instance till the original thread allows it.

Mutexes come to mind as those can be used to guard resources, but I only know of std::lock_guard that are in the scope of a single function, but do not add protection for all function calls in between lock and unlock.

Is it possible to protect a resource like that, when I know it will always call reserve and release in that order?

Snippet that explains it better:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex


struct information_t {
    std::mutex mtx;
    int importantValue = 0;

    // These should only be callable from the thread that currently holds the mutex
    void incrementIt() { importantValue++; }
    void decrementIt() { importantValue--; }
    void reset() { importantValue = 0; }

} protectedResource; // We only have one instance of this that we need to work with

// Free the resource so other threads can reserve and use it
void release()
{
    std::cout << "Result: " << protectedResource.importantValue << '\n';
    protectedResource.reset();
    protectedResource.mtx.unlock(); // Will this work? Can I guarantee the mtx is locked?
}

// Supposed to make sure no other thread can reserve or use it now anymore!
void reserve()
{ 
    protectedResource.mtx.lock();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[3];
    
    threads[0] = std::thread([]
    {
            reserve();
            protectedResource.incrementIt();
            protectedResource.incrementIt();
            release();
    });

    threads[1] = std::thread([]
        {
            reserve();
            // do nothing
            release();
        });

    threads[2] = std::thread([]
        {
            reserve();
            protectedResource.decrementIt();
            release();
        });

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A better idiom might be a [monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12647217/7478597) which keeps the lock of your resource and provides access to the owner. To obtain a resource, the `reserve()` could return such monitor object (something like a proxy to access the contents of the resource). Any competing access to `reserve()` would block now (as the mutex is locked). When the resource owning thread is done, it just destroys the monitor object which in turn unlocks the resource. (This allows to apply RAII to all this which makes your code safe and maintainable.)

Comment: "but do not add protection for all function calls in between lock and unlock." -- that premise is wrong or at least *very* misleading.

Comment: I agree. It's poorly phrased. How would you rephrase it, so it is more clear? Do you understand what I am trying to say with it?

Comment: Mutexes do not protect objects. They protect code from simultaneous execution. All pieces of code that you want protected from running simultaneously with each other (i.e. all critical member functions in your case) need to lock the same mutex. This is not ideal if these pieces of code can call each other, you need either a recursive mutex or another layer of member functions. A monitor is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion per comment:

> A better idiom might be a [monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12647217/7478597) which keeps the lock of your resource and provides access to the owner. To obtain a resource, the `reserve()` could return such monitor object (something like a proxy to access the contents of the resource). Any competing access to `reserve()` would block now (as the mutex is locked). When the resource owning thread is done, it just destroys the monitor object which in turn unlocks the resource. (This allows to apply RAII to all this which makes your code safe and maintainable.)

I modified OPs code to sketch how this could look like:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

class information_t {

  private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    int importantValue = 0;

  public:
    class Monitor {
      private:
        information_t& resource;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock;
    
      friend class information_t; // to allow access to constructor.
      
      private:      
        Monitor(information_t& resource):
          resource(resource), lock(resource.mtx)
        { }
      public:
        ~Monitor()
        {
          std::cout << "Result: " << resource.importantValue << '\n';
          resource.reset();
        }
      
        Monitor(const Monitor&) = delete; // copying prohibited
        Monitor& operator=(const Monitor&) = delete; // copy assign prohibited
    
      public:
        // exposed resource API for monitor owner:
        void incrementIt() { resource.incrementIt(); }
        void decrementIt() { resource.decrementIt(); }
        void reset() { resource.reset(); }
    };
    friend class Monitor; // to allow access to private members
  
  public:
    Monitor aquire() { return Monitor(*this); }
    
  private:
    // These should only be callable from the thread that currently holds the mutex
    // Hence, they are private and accessible through a monitor instance only
    void incrementIt() { importantValue++; }
    void decrementIt() { importantValue--; }
    void reset() { importantValue = 0; }

} protectedResource; // We only have one instance of this that we need to work with

#if 0 // OBSOLETE
// Free the resource so other threads can reserve and use it
void release()
{
    protectedResource.reset();
    protectedResource.mtx.unlock(); // Will this work? Can I guarantee the mtx is locked?
}
#endif // 0

// Supposed to make sure no other thread can reserve or use it now anymore!
information_t::Monitor reserve()
{ 
  return protectedResource.aquire();
}

using MyResource = information_t::Monitor;

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[3];
    
    threads[0]
      = std::thread([]
        {
          MyResource protectedResource = reserve();
          protectedResource.incrementIt();
          protectedResource.incrementIt();
          // scope end releases protectedResource
        });

    threads[1]
      = std::thread([]
        {
          try {
            MyResource protectedResource = reserve();
            throw "Haha!";
            protectedResource.incrementIt();
            // scope end releases protectedResource
          } catch(...) { }
        });

    threads[2]
      = std::thread([]
        {
          MyResource protectedResource = reserve();
          protectedResource.decrementIt();
            // scope end releases protectedResource
        });

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Result: 2
Result: -1
Result: 0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc4e4244a29addb1)

> Is it possible to protect a resource like that, when I know it will always call reserve and release in that order?

It's not anymore necessary to be concerned about this. The correct usage is burnt in:

- To get access to the resource, you need a monitor.
- If you get it you are the exclusive owner of the resource.
- If you exit the scope (where you stored the monitor as local variable) the monitor is destroyed and thus the locked resource auto-released.

The latter will happen even for unexpected bail-outs (in the MCVE the `throw "Haha!";`).

Furthermore, I made the following functions `private`:

- `information_t::increment()`
- `information_t::decrement()`
- `information_t::reset()`

So, no unauthorized access is possible. To use them properly, an `information_t::Monitor` instance must be acquired. It provides `public` wrappers to those functions which can be used in the scope where the monitor resides i.e. by the owner thread only.