Lock based concurrent vector
I am starting with designing thread safe data structure and looking to implement a concurrent vector that hides multi-threading complexity for the user and that offers thread safe clear function (which is not offered by Intel TBB::ConcurrentVector) . Considering a concurrent vector which is based on std::vector and locking a mutex for each call of clear or push_back functions of std::vector, how to iterate thread safely through the concurrent vector using for loop? in other terms, how to make iterate_thread in this minimal reproducible example thread safe?
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; // for the sake of minimal reproducible example
template<class T> 
class ConcurrentVector {
public: 
    ConcurrentVector() : mMutex{} 
                  , mVector{} 
    {}
    auto begin(){
        scoped_lock lk(mMutex);
        return mVector.begin(); 
    }
    auto end(){
        scoped_lock lk(mMutex);
        return mVector.end(); 
    }
    T& push_back(T t) {
        scoped_lock lk(mMutex);
        mVector.push_back(move(t)); 
        return mVector.back();
    }
    void clear() {
        scoped_lock lk(mMutex);
        mVector.clear(); 
    }
private: 
    mutex mMutex; 
    vector<T> mVector; 
}; 

int main(){
    ConcurrentVector<int> vec{};
    atomic_bool terminate_flag = false;
    jthread fill_thread{[&](){
        static int i = 0;
        while(!terminate_flag){
            this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
            vec.push_back(++i);
        }
    }};
    jthread clear_thread{[&](){
        while(!terminate_flag){
            this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
            vec.clear();
        }
    }};
    jthread iterate_thread{[&](){
        while(!terminate_flag){
            this_thread::sleep_for(400ms);
            for(auto i : vec){
                cout << i << ", ";
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }};
    
    this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
    terminate_flag = true;
    return 0;
}

Calling clear function in iterate_thread will invalidate iterator and actually, I am thinking of these two options:

Add getter function in ConcurrentVector to return a copy of the std::vector and iterating through it, but the issue here is that if clear is called in between, I will be iterating through the copy not the real existing data in the vector
or add a for_each function in ConcurrentVector that takes a callable, but the issue here is lack of safety as the user may be calling a locking function which causes a deadlock with the vector mutex

Are there other alternatives or could any of the two mentioned improved?

Question here should be self-contained. The link to Godbolt is nice as a bonus, but the code (in a form of a [mre]) should also be copy-pasted as text in the question.

Regarding your actual question: I would opt for the 2nd option (for_each with a callable). You can use a templated method to support all kinds of callables (lambda, std::function etc.).

"locking a mutex for each call of std::vector public member function" To synchronize access to elements this approach is flawed to begin with. For example user can call data() and then modify as they like, that a mutex was locked during that call does not do anything for protecting the elements

imho the most important lesson is that multithreading is not just single threaded plus threads (plus mutexes plus locks)

I have read your code and it has the same issue as I indicated above. Locking a mutex while calling begin and end does not do anything to protect what the caller will do with the iterators

#include <bits/stdc++.h> + using namespace std; == you just committed C++ suicide;

There is no use in hiding multithreading complexity. Instead, design APIs with a clearly delineated thread-local part and expose explicit synchronization primitives (eg commit() or compare_and_swap) Worst case you can do like Java and throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

@wohlstad the issue with callable is that if it locks other mutex it may cause a deadlock with the vector mutex

@pptaszni  using namespace std  is just for the sake of the minimal reproducible example

@Botje actually there is a use of TBB::ConcurrentVector, but what I am looking for is slightly different in requirement as clear function is needed on the threading flight, and much different in design

Whatever your end goal is, putting locks on individual operations clearly isn't the right solution. Suggest you ask a new question about the actual threading problem you're trying to solve. That way anyone solving your question has some concrete requirements and non-requirements to work with.

Please read Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

@JesperJuhl  using namespace std is just for the sake of the minimal reproducible example

@omarekik You didn't say so, so how would we know? There are thousands of questions here with that bad habit where people didn't just do it for the example, so I'm just pointing out that it's a bad idea - do with it what you want.

Easiest way to make something lockable is a monitor -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647217/making-a-c-class-a-monitor-in-the-concurrent-sense/48408987#48408987
And if you need to perform logically connected operations it includes a ManuallyLock choice.

@MikeVine thanks, the monitor is helpful to make std::vector lockable

@omarekik I updated that answer to show iterating over the object using the "locked handle" paradigm.

Do not export any vector-like functions from your class. Only export a function that returns an object acting as a scoped lock, and make that object export vector-like functions, which in turn won't need any locking. Something like:
ConcurrentVector<int> v; 
...
{
  auto vv = v.open(); // vv locks 
  for (auto& i: vv) {  // and presents vector-like functionality
    i = 2*i+3;
  }
  // vv's destructor unlocks
}


Thanks for the proposition, it hides mutex for the user but still he needs to call v.open and the for loop inside a scope and keep it as short as possible, in other terms still the user needs to be aware about multi-threading complexity.

There is no such thing as free lunch. You can hide complexity from the user, but for a rather heavy price

@omarekik take a quick look at what happened in Java when they made a thread-safe vector that hid all the complexity. TL;DR: They wound up with a class that was too slow most of the time and didn't provide the necessary protection most of the time. A really bad combination. The user needs to be involved in the scope of the lock, and this answer gives that with minimum impact..

Making a ConcurrentVector that wraps std::vector and locks on all public function calls is probably a bad idea. It will lead to an unnecessary number of lock/unlock calls, and it's generally undesirable to let other threads interleave between your calls. What I would recommend doing is to have one mutex for the entire vector, lock it with an RAII based lock class, perform all your actions and then let the destructor unlock the mutex at the end of the function. This generally achieves good performance and more predictable behavior.

Thanks for your proposition, the intention of ConcurrentVector is to hide multi-threading implementation for the user so he should not need to deal with mutex even though this may introduce some overhead

@omarekik in that case, I would propose to add a lock() method to the ConcurrentVector class, which returns a proxy object which can be used to access the vector, and also holds the mutex locked as long as the proxy is alive.

A range-based loop still uses iterators, even if not visible in code. That iterator has to cooperate. You can't just use std::vector::iterator for this, because the lock has to be released when the iterator goes out of scope.
The naïve implementation linked to only locks the mutex in .begin() when the iterator is created, which is way too short.
Locking the mutex while an iterator exists also prevents the problem of two iterators existing, causing write clashes. However, .end() does need to return a sentinel iterator even when there's another outstanding iterator.
Where things really break down is .end()-1. This needs to lock the vector, as the last element of the vector is definitely writeable.
And don't expect this to magically solve all your problems. Code like if (v.begin()!=v.end()) auto last = *(v.end()-1) breaks when another thread calls v.clear() at the wrong moment.

The proposed example contains a data race, as clear function would invalidate iterators. The question is how to avoid the data race within the implementation of ConcurrentVector so it can be safe and hiding multi-threading complexity.

@omarekik: "Hiding complexity" is a dark pattern. The pattern has  been invented over and over, and people keep discovering that hidden complexity is more dangerous than obvious complexity.

Thanks @MikeVine, this concurrent_vector is based on a monitor that protects std::vector from data race:
template<class t_container>
class monitor{
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    monitor(Args&&... args) : m_container(std::forward<Args>(args)...){}

    struct monitor_helper{//The time of locking is the life time of monitor_helper
        monitor_helper(monitor* mon) : m_monitor(mon), m_unique_lock(mon->m_mutex) {}
        t_container* operator->(){ return &m_monitor->m_container; }
        t_container& operator*(){ return m_monitor->m_container; } // for accessing using a manually locked object
        monitor* m_monitor;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_unique_lock;
    };

    monitor_helper operator->(){ return monitor_helper(this); }
    monitor_helper manually_lock(){ return monitor_helper(this); }
private:
    t_container m_container;
    std::mutex  m_mutex;
};

template<typename t_element> 
requires copyable<t_element>   
class concurrent_vector {
public: 
    void push_back(t_element t) {
        m_monitored_vector->push_back(move(t)); 
    }
    void clear() {
        m_monitored_vector->clear(); 
    }
    vector<t_element> get_data(){
        {//scope for manually_lock
            auto vector_lock_handler = m_monitored_vector.manually_lock();
            return *vector_lock_handler;
        }
    }
private: 
    monitor<vector<t_element>> m_monitored_vector; 
}; 

