# C++ Why does the automatic re-application of the arrow (->) operator not apply to pointer-to-pointer types?

Tags: c++, language-design

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677804/how-arrow-operator-overloading-works-internally-in-c) discusses how the arrow operator `->` is automatically re-applied to the return value of an overloaded `operator->()` until the value returned is a raw pointer, at which point the raw pointer is dereferenced as if with `->`. However, the same is not true when one has a pointer-to-pointer type that they wish to dereference to the base value - they must use `(*ptr_to_ptr)->foo()` instead. It seems to me that usage as `ptr_to_ptr->foo()` would be unambiguous, even more so than the automatic re-application of `->` onto returned values until a raw pointer is returned. So, what was the reasoning behind this decision?

minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dog {
    void bark() { std::cout << "woof!" << std::endl; }
};

struct DogWalker {
    Dog* dog;
    Dog* operator->() {
        return dog;
    }
};

struct DogOwner {
    DogWalker walker = { new Dog() };
    DogWalker operator->() {
        return walker;
    }
};

void main()
{
    DogOwner owner;
    owner->bark(); // works, prints "woof"

    Dog** ptr_to_ptr = new Dog*;
    *ptr_to_ptr = new Dog;
    (**ptr_to_ptr).bark(); // works
    (*ptr_to_ptr)->bark(); // works
    //ptr_to_ptr->bark(); // ERROR
    //C2227: left of '->bark' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
}
```

Comment: Because it doesn't - that's the way the language is defined.

Comment: Are you asking for standards committee discussion about the proposal and rejection of that language feature?  What if there is none?  `->` is much older than the `operator->()` you compare it to.

Comment: @DrewDormann I suppose that I would be. I tried to find some discussion about it and couldn't, so I asked here to see if anyone had any insight. There are numerous other questions on this site whose answers discuss why certain things work the way they do in c++, and I thought there might be an opportunity for similar discussion here. Your comment that `->` is much older than the `operator->()` is perhaps the starting point - would my question be better formulated as why `operator->()` has the automatic reapplication that it does?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Evidently. But is there some historical reason for the similar operations having different semantics?

Comment: The purpose of this is to allow for smart pointer classes, so they overload `->`. The repeated application allows them to return other smart pointers. But pointer-to-pointer is not the same thing.

Comment: Too complicated? Not necessary?

Comment: fyi The lanuage specifies that `p->m;`  is exactly equivalent to `(*p).m;`  So we need to include should `operator *` also be applied recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language adopts much of its semantics from C. The `->` operator when applied to a pointer type is only valid if the pointer points to a non-array composite type. Since C doesn't have classes, C++ defined its own semantics for the overloaded `->` that made sense for the smart pointer use cases.

You can achieve the behavior you want with a helper class.

```
template <typename T>
struct Unwrap {
    T *p_;
    Unwrap (T *p = 0) : p_(p) {}
    T * operator -> () const { return p_; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Unwrap<T *> {
    T **p_;
    Unwrap (T **p = 0) : p_(p) {}
    Unwrap<T> operator -> () const { return *p_; }
};

template <typename T>
Unwrap<T> make_unwrap (T *p) { return p; }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
struct foo {
    void bar () { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

int main () {
    foo p;
    auto pp = &p;
    auto ppp = &pp;
    auto pppp = make_unwrap(&ppp);

    pppp->bar();
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBSsQwEIbveYphBWkXCp7bmvM@wHoTSkyjBNtkSCeKlD57nXRbrKKsOQ3//DP/N9GIxYvW8411uoutgdr6gYJRvRSCTI@dIhbpA41TvYGzFNyOmuDBvQeFMArgd4YjNtVSrnqWJLiHuxxKwCbDHMZp84JHExT5AIWELAft3UAwQjAUg2N7BZOYqn8R1LxPfmH8xvEHyDYvr@Acr/DsFvXq1TRx9wP57ipeMq/oz96vyG/etvCkQsodYaC2LLWPBHUNh5PpOv/oDlu6sI44wrrFvIynRXg5WEXiOp16@125SD@0JO5oMzZgzhnJk9qFZKiMlWmePwE)

Comment: So essentially, it's because `->` on pointers came from C (so couldn't/shouldn't be changed), but C++ introduced the overloaded `operator->()`. Good to know, thanks, and helpful example!