# When and where should the ->* operator be overloaded?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am new to C++, and learning it, while learning operator overloading I came to know we can also overload  `->*`, in what cases we need it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c

Comment: Thanks for down voting it, now can you please explain its purpose and use case i understand +,- operator overloading, but whats the reason behind ->* over loading?

Comment: Above link does not describe its use case and purpose, or either i dont understand it :(, it mentions about syntax and i am clear for that...

Comment: @Will Vousden, thanks for making it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ operator overloading is a useful and very strong feature, but it's also one very easy to misuse with catastrophic results.

The rule of thumb is to follow the principle of no surprise. That is, the semantics of your operator overload should match those of the built-in version. *(Yes, there are exceptions such as domain-specific languages, boost::spirit etc., but these are isolated affairs).*

Let's apply this to `->*`. This operator can normally be invoked with a pointer as left operand and pointer to member as right operand. Therefore, you should only overload it in cases where you want to emulate such semantics. Let's say you're creating a pointer-like class, perhaps a handle or a special smart pointer (when those in `std` aren't applicable to your case). You might want to overload `->*` for your class then, to enable it to be used as much as a regular pointer as possible.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class LoggingPointer
{
  T *ptr_;
  std::ostream &log_;

public:
  T& operator* () const {
    log_ << "Deref";
    return *ptr_;
  }

  T* operator-> () const {
    log_ << "Access";
    return ptr_;
  }

  template <typename Mem>
  Mem& operator->* (Mem T::*arg) const {
    log_ << "Member access";
    return ptr_->*arg;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One place where we use the `->*` operator, is when we're manipulating method pointers.

As a method has to know in which object she is called, we could do:

```
class     A
{
    public:
          int    some_integer;

          void   add_then_print(int value)
          {
                  this->some_integer = this->some_integer + value;
                  std::cout << "My integer now: " << this->some_integer;
          }
};

typedef void    (A::*method_pointer)(int);
int    main(void)
{
    A*                   my_first_class_a = new A;
    A*                   my_second_class_a = new A;
    method_pointer       method = &A::add_then_print;         

    (my_first_class_a->*(method))(10);
    (my_second_class_a->*(method))(12);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you can see that the `add_then_print` method has been saved into `method`.

But in order to know what `this` represents in `add_then_print`, when we call a method using a method pointer, the syntax is as this:
`(object->*(method_pointer))(parameters_to_the_method);`

In some cases you'd maybe want to overload this operator to do something else than calling it with just the given parameters, or whatever you want.

Comment: How does this address the question, which asks about *overloading* `operator ->*`?

Comment: As mentioned, he's new to C++, before wondering why we would overload the ->* operator, he had to be sure to understand what's the ->* operator stands for. Then he can answer himself if he understands what he's asking. That's my POV, if it's useless i'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the answer you are looking for, but the only case where you need it is to confuse the hell out of anyone else on the project. And that includes you two weeks down the road. So please don't. Not everything that is possible to do is also a good idea to actually implement.

Comment: Unless you happen to be implementing a pointer-like class (such as a smart pointer or a special handle), in which case overloading `->*` enables familiar syntax with your class.