# C++ overloading dereference operators

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++, still trying to get a hang of the syntax. I've been taking a look at a few operator overloading examples, most recently smart pointer implementations. Here's a really generic example I'm looking at:

```
template < typename T > class SP
{
    private:
    T*    pData; // Generic pointer to be stored
    public:
    SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue)
    {
    }
    ~SP()
    {
        delete pData;
    }

    T& operator* ()
    {
        return *pData;
    }

    T* operator-> ()
    {
        return pData;
    }
};
```

When overloading the dereference operator why is the type T&? Similarly, when overloading the structure dereference why is the type T*?

Comment: `*p = 2` is often desired syntax. It would be a shame if it didn't do anything.

Comment: People usually at least attempt to forge consistency with there overloads. C++11 5.3.1p1 [expr.unary.op] lays out a `*` operator for pointer-types, and its not uncommon to mimic that (including overloads for `const` if you want to run the full gambit).

Answer (score 69):

The dereference operator (`*`) overload works like any other operator overload. If you want to be able to modify the dereferenced value, you need to return a non-const reference. This way `*sp = value` will actually modify the value pointed to by `sp.pData` and not a temporary value generated by the compiler.

The structure dereference operator (`->`) overload is a special case of operator overloading. The operator is actually invoked in a loop until a real pointer is returned, and then that real pointer is dereferenced. I guess this was just the only way they could think of to implement it and it turned out a bit hackish. It has some interesting properties, though. Suppose you had the following classes:

```
struct A {
    int foo, bar;
};

struct B {
    A a;
    A *operator->() { return &a; }
};

struct C {
    B b;
    B operator->() { return b; }
};

struct D {
    C c;
    C operator->() { return c; }
};
```

If you had an object `d` of type `D`, calling `d->bar` would first call `D::operator->()`, then `C::operator->()`, and then `B::operator->()`, which finally returns a real pointer to struct `A`, and its `bar` member is dereferenced in the normal manner. Note that in the following:

```
struct E1 {
    int foo, bar;
    E1 operator->() { return *this; }
};
```

Calling `e->bar`, where `e` is of type `E1`, produces an infinite loop. If you wanted to actually dereference `e.bar`, you would need to do this:

```
struct E2 {
    int foo, bar;
    E2 *operator->() { return this; }
};
```

---

To summarize:

1. When overloading the dereference operator, the type should be `T&` because that is necessary to modify the value pointed to by `pData`.
2. When overloading the structure dereference, the type should be `T*` because this operator is a special case and that is just how it works.

Answer (score 13):

The purpose of dereference operator is to dereference a pointer and returns the object reference. Hence it must return the reference. That is why it is T&.

The purpose of referring operator (->) is to return a pointer and hence T* is returned.

Comment: I think this question stems from the idea that "the purpose of operator-> is to return a pointer" is counter-intuitive.

The confusion is that: "(*x)." and "x->" both ultimately dereference x and access a member of the dereferenced pointer. So the fact that one operator "is meant to" return a pointer and the other a reference isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: and it's so easy to understand [similar concept](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

It is because pointer contains an address of a variable referencing it will give a reference (or to say a lvalue refrence) to the address it has stored.
e.g. `int x; int *p; p=&x;`  now `x` and `*p`  can be used interchangeably.
if you do `x =4;` or `*p = 4;` both will have same result. `*p` works as a reference to `x` just like a normal reference `int& t = x;` will work.

Next thing structure dereference operator. This operator gives you the access of member variables through a pointer to object of a class. In above example the member is `T*    pData;` so using this operator will give access to `pData` and `pData` is `T*` so the return type is `T*`. if `pData` in above example would have been `T` then the return type would have been `T`.

Comment: I interpret the added question "_Why is C++ designed in such way that operator* and operator-> are different in return types?_" like "Why does the `operator->()` overload _also_ add a built-in  dereferencing step if used via the built-in `->` operator - when the overload could just return `T&` directly _without_ adding any step afterwards (except adding an implied `.` between _object_ and a mandatory _member_)".

Answer (score 1):

### Overloaded operators are just functions

When overloading operaters you are free to return anything basicly (just like any other function), with the noteable exception of *member of pointer* `->` being somewhat special in this way.

In the example you show, a smart pointer, you aim to mimick the syntax of a pointer (pointer semantic). Then for syntax like:

```
*p = 2;
```

The indirection `operator*` return a *non-const reference* to object and we are able to modify through `operator*`. In effect, usually used for *proxy* type classes in the same way and it is a sort of a convention - but you could in theory return whatever.

The *member of pointer* operator `->` is a bit tricky. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We are making smart pointer and our aim is to access member of class/structure using any of this T& (reference) or T* (pointer) with flexibility.

for T* operator-> ():

```
T* operator-> ()
{
  return pData;
}
arrow operator (->) is a shorthand for (*p) and hence we return *pData which is of   type T*. 
here we are Overloding arrow operator so that members of T can be accessed like a pointer.
```

for T& operator* ():

```
T& operator* ()
{
  return *pData;
}
    * is "value at address" operator, here we are Overloding * (pointer) operator so 
    that members can be accessed  through a reference (T&).
```

We can change the behavior of the operator with operator overloading but its not recommended. overloaded operator behavior should be as close as its basic functionality.