# Pointer to member operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this link http://www.codingunit.com/unary-and-binary-operator-table. It says that **pointer to member** operator is a **binary operator**.

I have this code :

```
class test
{
public:
    int num;
    test(int j)
    {
        num=j;
    }
    test* operator->()
    {
        this->num;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test T(5);
    cout<<"Number is :"<<T->num;
}
```

As I know, non static member function of binary operator accepts one argument, but according to this program if I provide it one argument. It has an error, which says that *test* operator ->(int x)* should be *test* operator ->(**void**)* .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloading member access operators ->, .\* (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c)

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result, you need to change your program as follows:

```
test* operator->()
{
    return this;
}
};

int main()
{
test T(5);
cout<<"Number is :"<<T->num;
}
```

In your operator overloading function,  you should return `this` pointer. Since your operator overloaded function for `->` does not accept a parameter, so when you call it you don't need to pass a parameter value. So function call should be `T->num;`

Comment: This works as well .I had the output .When i do **this->num** without using return .It works fine as well.

Comment: When you use `this->num`, you are not invoking overloaded function operator. Even you comment your operator over loaded function, if you use `this-> num` will work.

Comment: Then what am i doing ?
I mean if i am not invoking , then i shouldn't get the ouput as well?

Comment: I already added answered to your question in second line in my previous comment