# C++ operator ->* and .*

Tags: c++, operators, dereference, member-access

Good day,

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c) question, but I'm specifically interested in the "object pointed to by member ..." type operators as listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) on Wikipedia.

I have never seen this in the context of actual code, so the concept appears somewhat esoteric to me.

My intuition says they should be used as follows:

```
struct A
{
    int *p;
};

int main()
{
    {
        A *a = new A();
        a->p = new int(0);
        // if this did compile, how would it be different from *a->p=5; ??
        a->*p = 5;
    }

    {
        A a;
        a.p = new int(0);
        // if this did compile, how would it be different from *a.p=5; ??
        a.*p = 5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile because `p` is undeclared. (See [example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95cae211df0e2638)

Could anyone please provide a real-world example of the use of operator->* and/or .* in C++?

Comment: Uhm, this is akin to asking for examples of multiplication operator. Too broad, IMHO. Have you tried googling for C++ member pointer, or tutorial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those operators are used for pointer-to-member objects. You won't come across them very often. They can be used to specify what function or member data to use for a given algorithm operating on `A` objects, for instance.

Basic syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int i;
    int geti() {return i;}
    A():i{3}{}
};

int main()
{
    {
        A a;
        int A::*ai_ptr = &A::i; //pointer to member data
        std::cout << a.*ai_ptr; //access through p-t-m
    }

    {
        A* a = new A{};
        int (A::*ai_func)() = &A::geti; //pointer to member function
        std::cout << (a->*ai_func)(); //access through p-t-m-f
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so they're only used in the context of pointer to members. I had the entire concept wrong. Not part of the original question, but why would one want to overload that operator though? The linked question's answer misses that part.

Answer (score 0):

The `->*` and `.*` syntax is the "pointer-to-member" operator that can be used to store pointers to members of a very specific object.

Usage example:

```
class A {
    public: int x;
};

int main() {
    A obj;
    int A::* memberPointer = &A::b;  //Pointer to b, which is int, which is member of A
    obj.*memberPointer = 42; //Set the value via an object

    A *objPtr = &obj;
    objPtr->*memberPointer = 21;  //Set the value via an object pointer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, too!

Comment: Your code does not use `.*` or `->*`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your example doesn't work.

Comment: @rozina You're right. I forgot the object instance before the *