# Can anyone help me to understand -> overloading to access data members in a class(c++)

Tags: c++

I need an easy example. I know basic overloading of operators like +,-,*,<<,>> etc. And please help to complete my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class XY
{
    int x,y;
public:
    XY()
    {
        x=0;y=0;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output,const XY &D )
    {
         output << "X : " << D.x << " Y: " << D.y;
         return output;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input,XY &D )
    {
        input >> D.x >> D.y;
        return input;
    }
```

-> overloading starts here

```
    XY* operator ->() 
    {

    }    
};
int main()
{
    XY a;
    cout<<"Enter value of x & y  "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a;
    //way to access members
    cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: Noone is forcing you to overload this operator (if this is not school homework), thus it is rather strange that you are asking what to put there. First you should know for what reason you want to overload it....

Comment: I read the title again, and maybe I got your point. I guess you misunderstood something. You do not have to overload anything to use the `operator->` to access members. Thats how its default implementation is working. You only have to overload it when you want to (mis-)use this operator to do anything else than accessing members of the class

Comment: That should be `XY* operator ->()`. Hint: there's only one `XY*` available for you to return in that function, and it's always available.

Comment: You should access the members here with `a.x`, not with `->`. But `x` would need to be public.

Comment: that's what I need to do. a.x I can write as a->x. as I am not using a class using pointer, i can't use a->x(not sure)

Comment: What research have you done on how overloading `->` works? What exactly don't you understand from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading member access operators ->, .\* (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c)

Comment: really speaking i haven't found anything helpful about -> overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make that code work as written since `x` and `y` are private.

If you make them public, this will work:

```
XY* operator ->() 
{
    return this;
}
```