# operator-> repeats until it returns a value of non-class type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-type

According to [13.3.1.2/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#8), or better [footnote-129](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#footnote-129) (emphasis mine):

> [...] The process repeats until an operator-> function **returns a value of non-class type**.

I thought I knew how `operator->` works (let me say, its *recursive* way based on the return type), but I see that I'm completely unaware about how it *actually* works (I mean, its *return type*).

When I found it, I wondered if one can really define and use something like a `double operator->()` for a generic struct `S`, for I've never used such an operator this way.
As an example, consider the code below:

```
struct S { 
    constexpr double operator->() noexcept {
        return 3.14;
    }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(3.14 == S{}.operator->(), "!");
}
```

The syntax is quite ugly and I cannot see any use of such an operator or a similar one.

What is the real purpose of letting the programmers return a `double` or a `float` from this operator?
What could be a possible use for them?

Comment: Well, you can _overload_ it. It doesn't necessarily require you to return a raw pointer type or dereference the actual struct that declares the operator.

Comment: There's no use for it. But there's also no strong motivation to prohibit it.

Comment: Well, this could also explain why it is not a _well known_ feature of the language. :-)

Comment: You can call that operator directly, but you can't use it in the normal way (`a->b`).

Comment: Apart from the fact that all the synapses in my left hemisphere are now definitively gone -thanks again @skypjack -, you may use this feature to change the class behavior given it is on the stack or not; if on the stack, you can select both, on the heap only one `operator->()`. Is this correct?

Comment: @fedino It's evil, most than everything else. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use for operator overloads is always questionable, and should be mostly consistent with the behavior of operators as seen with the intrinsic types.

Thus the overloading of the dereferencing operators `->` and unary `*` should behave like they are used with pointers:

Citing from [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719):

> #### Operators for Pointer-like Types
>
> For defining your own iterators or smart pointers, you have to overload the unary prefix dereference operator * and the binary infix pointer member access operator ->:
>
> ```
> class my_ptr {
>         value_type& operator*();
>   const value_type& operator*() const;
>         value_type* operator->();
>   const value_type* operator->() const;
> };
> ```
>
> Note that these, too, will almost always need both a const and a non-const version. *For the -> operator value_type must be of class (or struct or union) type, otherwise their implementation results in a compile-time error.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> The unary address-of operator should never be overloaded.
>
> For operator->*() see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777845/140719). It's rarely used and thus rarely ever > overloaded. In fact, even iterators do not overload it.

---

Obviously you can do that overload with `double` as return type, but that's no different from possible (non-sensical, less useful) overloads for other standard operators like e.g.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S { 
    constexpr double operator->() noexcept {
        return 3.14;
    }
    void operator=(const S& rhs) {}
 // ^^^^
    void operator<(const S& rhs) {}
 // ^^^^
};
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dcec301da5bd597)

```
int main() {
    static_assert(3.14 == S{}.operator->(), "!");
}
```

---

Your cite

> > [...] The process repeats until an operator-> function returns a value of non-class type.

merely means that the dereferencing operation will stop as soon a *non-class type* is received as return type. Thus returning an intrinsic type will stop calling the dereference operation.
If a pointer is returned, or another type that overloads `->` that operator will be called automatically upon the returned type.

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Not so sure if this statement is actually valid, my and OPs example seems to prove otherwise.</sub>

Comment: The statement that "otherwise their implementation results in a compile-time error" seems to be false: https://ideone.com/FD0DY7. Use in the more obvious way would be a problem, of course.

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes, that statement seems to be questionable, and my examples prove that being wrong. May be that changed with the current standard?

Comment: I don't think it's changed. It's so obvious that you have to return a pointer I suspect nobody ever tried not doing so. Bonus points to skypjack for guerrilla research coding.

Comment: Unary `*` is sometimes overloaded for non-pointer reasons, e.g. in the Boost Spirit parser it performs a function more like a wildcard match.

Comment: @M.M I'd say overloads are allowed for arbitrary return (and parameter) types.

Comment: @AlanStokes Guerrilla research coding? :-D ... It was obvious also to me that I have to return a pointer, that's way I found it interesting when I read the standard and saw that it was not mandatory. Useless, but interesting, isn't it? An obscure corner of the standard, at least for me...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suspect that the statement marked as (1) is false not because _we prove otherwise_, instead the standard says otherwise!! :-)

Comment: Thanks to @skypjack for pointing this out to me. I have now changed the FAQ. I apologize for the error.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the real purpose of letting the programmers return a double or a float from this operator?
>   What could be a possible use for them?

It works nicely with `std::map::iterator`. You can use:

```
std::map<int, int> m = { ... };

...

auto it  = m.find(10);
if ( it != m.end() )
{
   int val = iter->second;
}
```

Comment: For it applies iteratively. You win! :-)

Comment: That's a good answer to a different question :-) The `operator ->` there returns a pointer, and then the built-in operator takes over. `a->b` is ill-formed if `a` is double or float.

Comment: @AlanStokes Interesting indeed.