# Overloading '->' member access operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

While overloading `operator*` we do as follows:

```
T & operator * () {  return *ptr; }
```

That means if I have:

```
SmartPtr<int> obj(new int());
*Obj = 20;
Cout << *obj;
```

Then the `*obj` part is replaced by `*ptr` so its as good as:

```
*Ptr=20
cout<<*ptr
```

Now while overloading `operator->` we do the following:

```
T * operator -> () { return ptr; }
```

And it can be accessed as:

```
Obj->myfun();
```

What I don't understand here is after evaluating the  `obj->` is replaced by `ptr` so it should look as follows:

```
ptrmyfun(); // and this is syntax error
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: no, according to your logic * operator should also be replaced like *ptrobj, but that's not how it works, check this answer as it explains those tricky operators clearly http://stackoverflow.com/a/8782794/1936366

Comment: C++ does not work like search/replace in a text editor.

Comment: @Onur A. Why should * operator replace it with *ptrobj? It clearly should not. This problem would occur only in case of ->

Comment: I repeat: C++ does not work like search/replace in a text editor. "obj1->" is **not** replaced by `ptr` verbatim, as if this was a line of text in a text editor. The `->` operator results in the custom `operator->`() getting invoked. The return value from the operator function becomes the actual pointer to which the actual pointer dereference gets applied to. The End.

Comment: The `->` operator automatically chains the `->` of the result.  It can be another user-defined `->`, but this chaining continues until an actual pointer is returned.  So `Obj->myfun()` might be thought of as `(Obj->)->myfun()`.

Comment: @Sam, christopher : Yes that is it. Why dont one you guys Post this as an answer so that the same can be be accepted

Comment: Go ahead @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: @anurag86 according to your logic in the question, that leads to *ptrobj,
You said in your question Obj->myfun(); translates to ptrmyfun(); so applying your logic 
*Obj = 20; translates to *ptrObj = 20; but I reiterate that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not work like search/replace in a text editor. "obj1->" is not replaced by ptr verbatim, as if this was a line of text in a text file.

With:

```
Obj->myfun();
```

The fact that the `->` operator invokes a custom operator that returns `ptr`:

```
T * operator -> () { return ptr; }
```

That doesn't mean that the original statement somehow becomes

```
ptrmyfun();
```

As if "Obj->" was replaced by "ptr". C++ simply does not work this way, like search/replace in a text editor.

The `->` operator results in the custom `operator->()` getting invoked. That part, of how you understand operator overloading works, is correct.

But what happens is that, simply, the return value from the `operator->`() becomes the actual pointer value to which the actual pointer dereference gets applied to.

So this becomes, essentially:

```
ptr->myfun();
```

That's all.