# arrow operator (operator->) return type when dereference (operator*) returns by value

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm writing an InputIterator, which implements, among others, operator* and operator->.

My operator* returns a pair of references to (vector) elements. Operator* returns by value therefore.

According to cppreference:

> The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded.

What do I return then?

I cannot return a raw pointer; the pair has to be returned physically somehow. 
So possibly some wrapper with operator-> defined? Does it exist in standard library, or how is it generally done?

Comment: I thought I could return a wrapper which would hold the value as a data member and would have an operator-> defined to return pointer to its data member. But does it exist in std library?

Comment: use `std::pair` or so

Comment: But the iterator class or structure should already *be* a "wrapper", that references an element in your "container". Easiest solution for iterators is to either contain the current position, and from that you can get the "value" ("object") being referenced.  Then it's easy to return a pointer to the referenced element.

Comment: As a rough rule, if a class' `operator*()` (dereference) returns a value rather than a reference, it would be appropriate to question whether it should have an `operator->()` AT ALL.    Idiomatically, `object->a` and `(*object).a` would normally be a reference to (or value of) the same entity, and achieving that is rather involved or sometimes impossible if `operator*()` returns by value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not my case, but if you had more iterators in a vector e.g. and sequentially processed them, the iterators with the value type stored would take excessive space as opposed to iterators returning a wrapper/proxy on dereference/->.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my iterator does not correspond one-to-one with the underlying container. It picks just some elements and returns pairs of them. Theoretically I could return them one by one, but I would have to join them to pairs later in code, which I don't think is more elegant in my case.

Comment: I understand your problem better now I think. My primary solution would be the same as the note in the [answer from dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856428/440558): Keep a copy of the pair in the iterator itself, and return a pointer to the pair when needed. Keep it simple, don't overengineer things. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct fake_ptr_with_value {
  T t;
  T* operator->() { return std::addressof(t); }
};
```

return a `fake_ptr_with_value<decltype(**this)>`.

No such helper type is exposed from `std`.

Please note that due to defects in the specifications of what various iterator classes require, this is only usable for `InputIterator`s.  Forward iterators (and all more powerful iterators, like random access iterators), under the standard, require that `operator*` return a reference to a true and stable object.

The defect is that the standard (a) in some cases requires references when pseudo-references would do, (b) mixes "iteration" and "dereference" semantics.

Rangesv3 has a more decoupled iterator category system that addresses some, if not all, of these defects.

As this question is about input iterators, this solution is sufficient; I am just including this caution in case someone wants to use this technique elsewhere.  Your code may compile and seem to work, but you are almost certainly going to be violating the requirements of the C++ standard when you pass your iterator to any `std` function, which means your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required.

Comment: And when someone does `auto const& foo = it->foo;` they have a dangling reference?

Comment: @ayxan yes, they made a dangling reference there.  That is one of the limitations of input iterators; you are not guaranteed `*` or `->` object long term existence.

Comment: It's interesting that `auto const& ref = *it` is OK but `auto const& foo = it->foo` dangles. I do understand the reason but it's a bit deceiving.

Comment: @Ayxan Wait until you play with `(*it).foo`.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use `decltype(std::addressof(t)) operator->()`?

Comment: @MarcDirven `std::addressof` is guaranteed to return a pointer to its argument.  Anything that makes it fail to do that means your program is already ill formed no diagnostic required.  So, no, I'd rather see an error if they disagree.  And if they do agree, your version is harder to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Since [`->` will continue "drilling down" until it hits a pointer return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c), your code could return a "proxy" for the pair with the pair embedded in it:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class pair_proxy {
    std::pair<T1,T2> p;
public:
    pair_proxy(const std::pair<T1,T2>& p) : p(p) {}
    std::pair<T1,T2>* operator->() { return &p; }
};
```

**Note:** I would strongly consider embedding `std::pair` in your iterator, and returning a pointer to it from your `operator ->()` implementation.

Comment: Embedding is *necessary* to be a `ForwardIterator`.  (This is a bit unfortunate, since for many types multi-pass algorithms can be written efficiently even with by-value `operator*`.)