# clarification on overloading the -> operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how overloading -> operator works. I have the following classes

```
class Message {

public:
    Message(string message) :m_text(message) {}
    void printText() {
        cout << "text is " << m_text << endl;
    }
    string m_text;
};


class MessagePointerWrapper
{
public:

    MessagePointerWrapper(string message)  {
        m_message = std::make_unique<Message>(message);
    }

    Message* operator->() {

        return m_message.get();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Message> m_message;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    MessagePointerWrapper messageWrapper =  MessagePointerWrapper("Hello World");
    messageWrapper.m_message->printText();
    messageWrapper->m_text = "PQR";
    messageWrapper.m_message->printText();
}
```

The `MessageWrapper` class's `->` operator is overloaded to return a `Message*`.
So in the main method when I call `messageWrapper->` what it returns is a `Message*`. Usually when I have a pointer, I need to use `->` operator or the deference operator to access the object.
According to that logic, to access the `m_text` veriable of the `Message` object, the code should be written as below

```
(messageWrapper->)   // this returns a pointer to Message. so to access the object, I should write as
(messageWrapper->)->m_text = "PQR"
```

or

```
*(messageWrapper->).m_Text = "PQR"
```

but this does not work that way and I need to call it as

```
messageWrapper->m_text = "PQR";
```

I don't understand the logic here. Can I get a clarification on this please.

==============

Some further notes :

In the main method I saw the below two methods do the same thing

```
messageWrapper.operator->()->m_text = "JKH";

messageWrapper->m_text = "JKH";
```

does it mean the operator `->` works different from other operators where it means

`messageWrapper->`  is equivalent to `(messageWrapper.operator->())->`
and not `messageWrapper.operator->()` as is the case of other operators.

Comment: `*(messageWrapper->).m_Text` is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Can you kindly explain why. that's what I don't understand. (messageWrapper->) is a pointer to a messge. dereferncing that pointer to access the object should be either (messageWrapper->)-> or  *(messageWrapper->)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overloading-member-access-operators-c][1].
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the standard states, [[over.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ref#1)

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

That means `messageWrapper->m_text` is a syntax sugar of `(messageWrapper.operator->())->m_text`. You can apply the latter style explicitly, but the former is more efficient. The overloaded `operator->` makes it possible to use the class like raw pointers, and that's how smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` work.

Answer (score 5):

The standard says :

> **13.5.6 Class member access**
>
> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class
>   object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is
>   selected as the best match function by the overload resolution
>   mechanism

Answer (score 3):

-> is a binary operator, it works using both arguments and will continue to resolve the left hand side so long as it is not a pointer.

That is, in the following code after the call to Wrapper2::operator ->() the compiler sees that the return type is a reference and calls Wrapper1::operator ->, only then does the call result in a pointer and 'm' is resolved against RealType.

```
struct RealType
{
    int m;
};

class Wrapper1 {
    RealType rt;

public:
    RealType * operator ->() { return &rt; }
};
class Wrapper2 {
    Wrapper1 w1;

public:
    Wrapper1 & operator->() { return w1; }
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper2 w;
    w->m = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The operator -> has to return a pointer, when it is used the return value is auto de-referenced, so you don't have to deference it by yourself adding a second ->