# overloading composite operator in c++ (.*)

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have implemented a `Matrix` class implementation for matrix manipulation, and so far i can overload ordinary (single) operators such as `+`, `*`, ...

I want to do Matrix elementary multiplication by overloading the operator (.*), such as i can write

```
Matrix A(5,3), B(5, 3), C;
C = A .* B;
```

C, in this case, will hold the value of multiplication element by element from A and B (A and B have same dimensions)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 my question is can I technically overload the operator (.*) (point star), in case we can, how?

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777845/4139593)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading member access operators ->, .\* (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c)

Comment: there is `std::val_array` which supports element wise operations

Comment: Do you need this specific syntax (it's impossible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this operator overloading reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

> ## Restrictions
>
> - The operators `::` (scope resolution), `.` (member access), `.*` (member access through pointer to member), and `?:` (ternary conditional) cannot be overloaded.

In short, it's not possible to overload the "dot" member access operators like `.*`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) you can see the "pointer to member of object" `.*` operator is not overloadable in c++.