# Build a wrapper-class for a pointer to pointer in c++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a small wrapper-class that lets me use a pointer to a pointer like
it was just a normal pointer(just for convenience).
I came up with the following code:

```
template<typename T>
    class PtrPtr
    {
    public:
        PtrPtr() = default;
        PtrPtr(const T** ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {  }
        inline void operator =(const T** ptr) { m_ptr = ptr; }
        inline void operator =(T** ptr) { m_ptr = ptr; }

        inline operator T*() const { return (*m_ptr); }

        inline T** get() const { return m_ptr; }
    private:
        T** m_ptr;
    };
```

I thought the operator `inline operator T*() const { return (*m_ptr); }` would
make it possible to use the class as if it were a pointer to T, however it doesn't seem to work
when I try to access T's elements with the following syntax:

```
PtrPtr<myStruct> ptr = function that returns a pointer to pointer to myStruct;
ptr->some member of myStruct; <-Gives an error
static_cast<myStruct*>(ptr)->some member of myStruct; <-works but obviously tedious syntax
```

Note that when I specifically cast "PtrPtr ptr" to a T* and then try to access its
members with the "->"-operator it seems to work.
Any Ideas if it is possible to acheive a clean syntax here?

Comment: `->` is an operator, so you will need to overload it too

Comment: Thank you so much, that works brilliantly and is exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to over load the `->`-operator.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators)  thread explains how it is done.