# OOP Design Question (MFC C++ implementation)

Tags: c++, oop, mfc

I have a GUI to interact with the user, but I have an OOP design problem with this.

Through a dialog the user specifies `CDiscreteDistribution`s and they are stored in a `std::vector<CDiscreteDistribution*>` in the `MyAppDoc` class for serialization. Through another dialog the user chooses a type of `CDistribution` for a particular `CParameter`. `CDiscreteDistribution`, `CConstantDistribution`, and `CContinuousDistribution` inherit `CDistribution`, and `CParameter` has a polymorphic pointer to a `CDistribution` member variable. `MyAppDoc` has a container class of `CParameter`. Thus the `CDiscreteDistribution`s are pointed two twice, but only exist once.

In summary, `MyAppDoc` has

1. `std::vector<CDiscreteDistribution*>`
2. `CContainer` which has many `CParameter` which have

   - `CDistribution*` which can point to one of

     - `CDiscreteDistribution` which is one of the `CDiscreteDistribution*`s stored above
     - `CConstantDistribution` created/destroyed by `CParameter`
     - `CContinuousDistribution` created/destroyed by `CParameter`

This design pattern is causing me various nightmares in porting the app to use `shared_ptr` due to double deletes and serialization (boost). Should one of the pointers to `CDiscreteDistribution` be a `weak_ptr`? If so where should own the pointer?

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT:
I re-thought the reasoning for having `std::vector<CDiscreteDistribution*>` and it was just to avoid copying the vector into and out of the GUI. But the objects are quite small, and so I've broken the link between them and suffer the minor performance implications. Now `MyAppDoc` has:

1. `std::vector<CDiscreteDistribution>`
2. `CContainer` which has many `CParameter` which have

   - `CDistribution*` which can point to one of

     - `CDiscreteDistribution` created/destroyed by `CParameter`, copied from one of the `CDiscreteDistribution`s stored above
     - `CConstantDistribution` created/destroyed by `CParameter`
     - `CContinuousDistribution` created/destroyed by `CParameter`

I think part of the problem was `boost::serialization` made two `shared_ptr`s for each `CDiscreteDistribution` that weren't aware of each other's existence. Now the only issue is backwards compatibility to files created with the previous versions.

I figure this 'solution' is actually just avoiding a proper design!

Comment: It would probably help if you simplified or generalized your specific case a bit.  Can you turn this into more of a `Base`/`Derived` abstract example to demonstrate what your problem with shared pointers / etc. is?  I find it hard with the question as written to really know what the class of problems you're running up against are...

Comment: Thanks Mr Fork, you're right, but I'll leave it since the other responses have used the same nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

The question is described not enough to understand the full situation, complications and exact problem, but in general -

- I assume you want to use shared_ptr to not have to manually delete() objects
- If so, see if you can solve it by not using shared_ptr, but rather using boost::ptr_vector instead of a vector of raw pointers; the ptr_vector will then handle memory management for you.

I'm not even sure what the shared_ptr would bring you - it's quite obvious, I'd say from my limited understanding of the situation, that the Doc owns the CDiscreteDistribution objects. Whoever owns the other two types of Distributions is responsible for deleting them; this can be done though a shared_ptr or otherwise. (you say 'locally instanced' but that doesn't mean much - are they instantiated on the heap or the stack? What is their lifetime? Why is their lifetime different from the DiscreteDistribution objects? What is 'local' - local to what?)

Comment: Thanks Roel, I hadn't thought of ptr_vector. Since the objects are polymorphic I wanted to handle all the Distributions the same way within CParameter. I think my idea above does this, but as I say it probably avoids a better design!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roel that the question is not fully specified.  But having done several extensive conversions from raw pointers to `shared_ptr`, I can give you a little advice.

1. `weak_ptr` should not be necessary unless you have circular dependencies.  In other words, if an object A has a `shared_ptr` to object B and object B has a `shared_ptr` back to object A.  In this case, it's impossible for the reference count of either pointer to go to 0, so you would either need to manually intervene to break the cycle, or use `weak_ptr` to designate one side as dependent.
2. I'm confused why you have issues with double deletion when using `shared_ptr`.  One of the advantages of smart pointers in general is that you don't have to actually delete them.  If you've converted *all* your raw pointers to `shared_ptr`, you shouldn't have this problem.  If your `CConstantDistribution` and `CContinuousDistribution` objects are actually locals rather than allocated with `new` (I can't tell 100% if this is the case from your description), you can make them `shared_ptr` objects that are initialized in your constructor, if you can change the app's code.  This would allow you to make your `std::vector<CDiscreteDistribution*>` a container of `shared_ptr` to `CDiscreteDistribution` instead.  At that point, you shouldn't have to worry about deleting those objects at all, unless you have circular references as described above.  Even if you do, you'd have converted a double-delete crash to a memory leak, which is generally less bad.
3. Serialization can be tough.  Since you've tagged the question with MFC, I'll assume you're using MFC serialization.  I generally don't have problems when wrapping everything in `shared_ptr` when I serialize out to a file -- I just use `.get()` on the smart pointer object and serialize the resulting raw pointer.  When I serialize in, I read the raw pointer from the serialized file and wrap it in the `shared_ptr` candy coating at that point.  It's a little extra code in the serialization function, but it works.

If I've guessed inaccurately on some of your situation, feel free to add a comment.  I'd be happy to help further if I can.

Comment: Thanks for the help mwigdahl! I think the double deletion was caused by boost::serialization creating two shared_ptr's to the same object. This is rectified by my 'solution' above.

Comment: Cool, good luck!  Certainly, passing first-class objects around is much easier from a lifetime management perspective, if you can do it!

Comment: What do you mean by first-class objects? As in the objects themselves, and not pointers to the objects?

Comment: Yes, according to the definition in the answer to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695169/are-raw-c-pointers-first-class-objects